# LESS: Including string globalvars in CLI

Tags: css, linux, less, command-line-interface

So I'm trying to include a string globalvar on the command line. According to the docs ( http://lesscss.org/usage/ ), it should be straightforward:

`lessc --global-var="my-background=red"`

However, if the value is a string (instead of a CSS colour in the example), it needs to be quoted, giving:

`lessc --global-var="staticbase='static'"`

But running that against my less file gives me:

> NameError: variable @staticbase is undefined in /tmp/tmpoRLm7A on line 336, column 133:
>
> `336 ul.popular {  background: url('@{staticbase}/background.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat; }`

I've tried a variety of ways of escaping the various quotes, but nothing seems to work. The same less file compiles fine using the client-side library, with `less.globalVars['staticbase']` set.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results with current less version (`--global-var="staticbase='static'"` works fine for me). Though do you realize that in this particular case quotes are not really necessary neither for the variable itself nor for the value inside `url`?

Comment: Hmm, if I don't quote the value inside url(), less' variable processing doesn't trigger, and it just outputs `@{staticbase}`.

What version of lessc are you using? Mine is 1.4.2

Comment: @AndrewHows: I am using 2.0 and it is the same when single quotes is not given within url. That should be because you need to do string concatenation. I guess what seven-phases-max meant is neither the variable requires quotes nor the url should be like `'static'/background...`. Both `--global-var="staticbase=static"` and `--global-var="staticbase='static'"` worked fine for me.

Comment: You and seven-phases have hit upon the solution. It was a version issue - upgrading to 2.0 fixed it. I guess the documentation I was relying on was for version 2.0 as well, which explains that.

I should have checked that, but I only installed it a couple of months ago, and didn't think it would have changed so dramatically.

Thanks.

(Not sure how to assign credit for solving the issue, when only comments have been left)

Comment: @AndrewHows: The most important thing is that the problem is resolved mate. Credit must go to seven-phases-max because I only elaborated/clarified his comment.